# Clone raspberry sd from 32 to 16 GB

Tags: sd-card, data-transfer

I have [openelec](https://openelec.tv) on my Raspberry Pi board installed on a 32 GB microsd but it occupies way less space so I'd like to move the whole OS to a 16 GB microsd, I tried to clone using win32diskImager but I got a 32 GB .img file, do you know any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do a backup of your current 32GB SD
2. You will get a 32GB *.img file, this is OK
3. Get any Linux computer and download [this tool (PiShrink)](https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink)
4. Use it like this: `./pishrink my32Gbfile.img newimagefile.img`

Check the size of `newimagefile.img` file, maybe it will fit on your 16GB SD card.

Comment: can I use a virtual machine?

Comment: @ScazzoMatto yes, you can also use your own Pi to run PiShrink :smile: