# How to shrink down Debian to fit onto 1GB SLC-SD-Card?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, filesystem, image

I am using a Raspberry Pi in an industrial area as a data-logger and had to deal with SD-Card wear so that I decided to use SLC-SD-Cards with higher quality.

To keep costs for those card types low, I am currently trying to figure out how to shrink down the Raspbian Image to a very small size so that it will fit onto a 1GB (or 2GB in the bad case) SD-Card!

I have purged a lot of packages - including X11 - but still have a disk usage of remaining 1,8GB. Less would be better!

What I need for running my application is:

- Python 2.7.x
- lighttpd-Web-Server
- PHP
- RRD-Tool
- SPI-Library
- Bonjour/Zeroconf

I was also thinking of using a different system - other than Debian, like buildroot but I have absolutely no clue if this is necessary and what to do to install buildroot linux.

Additionally I could ask this the other way round: When using the official 'Lite' version of the Raspbian System it comes with a size of approx. 1.3GB which is - like mentioned in the comments below - a bit closer to my 1GB. But where do that 1.3 GB come from when all I want to do is put up a very small websever + python script and a database of less than 5MB !? Or. How to remove those things I don't need?

Comment: I still haven't gotten round to checking the actual installed size, but have you considered starting with [Jessie Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/), rather than the full version? It *should* come in at something like 1.3GB installed (I think), which is at least closer to your 1GB target. You may have to do some extra work installing missing packages.

Comment: You refer to Debian, which Raspbian more-or-less is, but you *can* run actual stock Debian on some models of Pi and you've tagged this `Raspbian` -- also from context it seems pretty clear that's what you mean.  Anyway, the "jessie-lite" image is I think < 2 GB unpacked.  Note that by filling all the space on an SD card you will be reducing its lifespan due to [wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling), depending on how much writing is involved. If a cheap is card packed full and used 24/7, you could be looking at months. This may not be as "economical" a choice as you think.

Comment: In response to your edit, not everyone wants to run a webserver. Some people want to do other things. Hence: 1.3GB. Lite is still just Raspbian with bits left off. You can take *even more* bits off if it's still too big and you can find anything spare.

Comment: Hmmm. [Minibian](https://minibianpi.wordpress.com/) [claims a 477MB installed size](https://minibianpi.wordpress.com/features/). You may need so many packages it'll erode the savings, but interesting.

Comment: I believe from some of the things said here by Minibian users that it is 1) Not kept up-to-date, 2) Does not have a complete repo creating a PITA if you need stuff that isn't in it.  But you can search here for that info yourself, and by all means, give it a spin.

Comment: You can try to Shrink your image file. Read [this topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49987/clone-raspberry-sd-from-32-to-16-gb/49995#49995)

Comment: I created a utility for this:
[RaspberryPiShrink](https://github.com/audstanley/RaspberryPiShrink)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran `du -h` on the root partition of a recent (March 2016) jessie-lite image -- as in, one that is totally unmodified and unused.  The total volume *of data* is **714 MB**.

That would not include most of the items on your list (I am sure it includes python 2.7.x as this is a fundamental requirement, and avahi, a zeroconf implementation, is stock), but in any case, to be sane  (as opposed to "short-sightedly clever"), and because of what I mentioned in a comment about [wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling), I strongly advise against using anything smaller than a 2 GB card.  I think your clients will prefer something that cost a couple of extra bucks vs. something that is going to fail later this year.

I do not think the remainder of your list would take much space, BTW, perhaps a few hundred MB at most (PHP and RRD-tool are wildcards for me, dependency wise).

Note that the actual size of the partition is larger than than 714 MB; the uncompressed image is ~1.3 GB, which includes a 60 MB boot partition that is half full, but you could shrink it down to fit on a 1 GB card, or, again, to be **sane**, expand it to fill a 2 GB card.

> How to remove those things I don't need?

There is not much there to remove that you don't need, which is the whole point of the `lite` image.  To emphasize my point about sanity: Depending on a remote, long running unit with a writable root partition that is 90%+ full *is complete foolishness and you will get what you deserve if you follow that path*.